# Группы radiobutton в табах tabcontrol

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Не работают группы при переключении вкладки в tabcontrol

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="375" Margin="0,111,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="955">
<TabItem Header="1">
    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
        <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="291,379,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158" GroupName="gr1"/>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="2">
    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
        <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="291,379,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158" GroupName="gr1"/>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

То есть возможно одновременно зачекить и `radiobutton` в первом табе, и во втором.

Как то можно решить эту проблему, а то я боюсь, что если каждый раз програмно выключать `radiobutton~ы` в другом табе, то будет снижение производительности.

Попробовал сделать топорное програмное выключение отмеченного чекбокса в одном табе, когда отмечается чекбокс в другом путем создания  двух массивов с чекбоксами, назначения событий "Checked" в XAML, в которых путем

```
arrayRadio1[i].IsChecked = false
```

или `arrayRadio2[i].IsChecked = false`

отключается чекбокс в другом табе. Это сработало, но это как-то это не очень элегантно.

Comment: Снижение производительности? Не смешите. Проигрывание анимации при выборе радиобаттона занимает на порядок больше времени, чем те несколько микросекунд, за которые проходит code-behind (и микросекунды только из-за DependencyProperty, а так были бы наносекунды).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Окей, если вы хотите сделать это через чистый XAML, `GroupName` не обязательно сработает. В нормальных случаях он работает, но `TabControl` удаляет невидимый таб из визуального дерева, поэтому радиобаттоны в невидимом табе не влияют на остальные.

Поэтому сделаем вот как: раздадим каждому RadioButton'у по идентификатору, и будем хранить текущий RadioButton в attached property.

Получаем следующий код:

```
// attached property
static class RadioButtonExtension
{
    public static string GetRadioButtonSelection(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(RadioButtonSelectionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRadioButtonSelection(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RadioButtonSelectionProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadioButtonSelectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RadioButtonSelection", typeof(string),
                                            typeof(RadioButtonExtension));
}

// конвертер, для данного id выясняет, текущий ли это id
public class RadioButtonSelectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null && value.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value.Equals(true))
            return parameter;
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Дальше просто пользуемся:

```
<TabControl x:Name="OuterTabControl">
    <TabItem Header="1">
        <RadioButton
            Content="RadioButton"
            IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=OuterTabControl,
                                Path=(local:RadioButtonExtension.RadioButtonSelection),
                                Converter={StaticResource RadioButtonSelectionConverter},
                                ConverterParameter=id1}"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="2">
        <RadioButton
            Content="RadioButton"
            IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=OuterTabControl,
                                Path=(local:RadioButtonExtension.RadioButtonSelection),
                                Converter={StaticResource RadioButtonSelectionConverter},
                                ConverterParameter=id2}"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

(Код адаптирован [отсюда](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3b07622f-2244-48c1-ad14-9769a9e79d35/how-to-split-a-group-of-radio-buttons-across-tabs?forum=wpf).)

---

Можно, разумеется, переписать вручную `TabControl` так, чтобы он просто прятал неактивные табы:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Но это, наверное, не лучшее решение.

Comment: А попроще нельзя? Потому что я его не сильно понимаю, и по этому не смогу его модифицировать для своих нужд. Попробовал вручную, radiobutton1.IsChecked = false при выборе второго, но почему-то это не работает.

Comment: @Theonic: Нууууу... Вроде в интернете никто лучше не предложил. Сейчас попробую расписать, как работает. Если будет непонятно, переспрашивайте.

Comment: Например, не найден префикс local.

Comment: @Theonic: А почему не работает, должно же! Выложите минимальный воспроизводящий пример отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Окей, `local` — это подключение неймспейсов в XAML. Его, понятно, надо подключить вручную. Как-то так: http://pastebin.com/YBhWiLKt (только замените SO11 на настоящее имя неймспейса и возможно assembly — Intellisense подскажет).

Comment: Говорит, что не найден RadioButtonSelectionConverter, хотя мэйнспейс, где лежит этот класс, я подключил. У меня это основной мэйнспейс приложения. Надо еще как-то сборку подключить? xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectWPF"

Comment: @Theonic: Нет, должно работать. Перекомпилируйте?

Comment: @Theonic: Или покажите код.

Comment: код я просто скопировал. Классы лежат в основном мейнспейсе, xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectWPF" - так подключил. Ребилд не помог.

Comment: Должно работать, у вас какая-то опечатка. Выложите код на pastebin? Или если хотите, я выложу полный проект куда-нибудь.

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, если вас не затруднит. А почему у меня не сработал вариант с ручным выключением, который я в вопросе написал?

Comment: Хотя нет, ручной вариант сработал. Наверное, остановлюсь на нем. Но все равно не понятно, почему xaml не видит существующий класс. Возможно, надо было добавить сборку?

Comment: По ссылке на msdn класс подключен                                                               <Window.Resources>
    <local:RadioButtonSelectionConverter x:Key="RadioButtonSelectionConverter"/>
  </Window.Resources>

Comment: @Theonic: Сейчас гляну, момент.

Comment: А где вы прописываете `xmlns:local`? Техника с подключением своего namespace'а **очень** часто используется, поэтому я бы посоветовал разобраться.

Comment: <Page x:Class="repetitorWPF.page.intervals.pSIntervals"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:ProjectWPF"

Comment: @Theonic: У вас случайно неймспейс не `repetitorWPF.page.intervals`? Объявление `local` правильное, если только ваш `RadioButtonSelectionConverter` действительно лежит в неймспейсе `ProjectWPF` (а не, например, в `repetitorWPF.page.intervals.ProjectWPF`). Перепроверьте!

Comment: Проверил. Именно в ProjectWPF лежит.

Comment: @Theonic: Тогда может, скиньте куда-нибудь проект. Или тестовый проект.